# A couple of questions about bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory

> a.  Show that a $4$-regular graph having $15$ vertices cannot be bipartite.
>
> b. Find a bipartite graph having the degree sequence $(4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2)$.
>
> c.  Show that there is no bipartite graph having the degree sequence $(6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)$.

a.  Partition the $15$ vertices into two disjoint sets $A, B$ with $|A| = 7, \ |B| = 8.$ Then the sum of degrees in $A$ is $28$ and the sum of degrees in $B$ is $32.$ In bipartite graphs, these sums must be equal.

b. Consider two disjoint sets $X =\{a, b, c, d\}, \ Y = \{e, f, g, h, i\}$ where $\deg(a) = 4, \ \deg(b) =3,\ \deg(c) = 3, \ \deg(d) = 3,\ \deg(e) = 3, \ \deg(f) = 3, \ \deg(g) = 3, \ \deg(h) = 2, \ \deg(i) = 2.$

One possible relation where $\to$ stands for "connects to" is $a \to h, i, \\ b \to  e, \\ c \to  f, \\ d \to g.$

c. Consider the bijection $(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m) \leftrightarrow (6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)$ and the disjoint sets $X = \{a, b, d, e, f, g, h\}, \ Y = \{c, i, j, k, l, m\}.$ The sum of degrees in $X \ne$ sum of degrees in $Y.$

Do my answers make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your answer for (a), you have only shown that no bipartite graph exists in the case where $|A| = 7$ and $|B| = 8$.  You need to generalize by showing that for any choice of $|A|$ and $|B|$ satisfying $|A| + |B| = 15$, the sum of degrees in each set cannot be equal, and of course, this has to do with the fact that the number of vertices is odd, yet the graph is $2k$-regular.

For (b), your specification is incomplete.

For (c), you haven only shown that the particular partition of the vertex set does not result in a bipartite graph.  You need to show that **no** partition exists; this requires considering all possible unique (up to degree sequence) partitions of the vertex set.

Comment: (a). Since the number of vertices of the given $4$-regular graph is odd, $|A| = \text { odd and }  |B| = \text { even}$ or vice versa and thus $|A|$ never equals $|B|?$

Answer (score 1):

a. Suppose that it is possible to form a bipartite graph by partitioning the vertex set into two sets with $n$ and $m$ vertices. Then  equality of sum of degree of vertices in each partition gives $4n=4m$ with total number of vertices $n+m=15$ which is not possible.

b. Note that each partition must have sum of degree of its vertices equal to $13$ and for this to be possible, one partition must have $4$ and other $5$ vertices together with degrees $4, 3, 3, 3$ and $3, 3, 3, 2, 2$ respectively.

c. If a bipartite graph were possible then each partition will have sum of degree of vertices equal to $29$, but the degree of all vertices are even.

Comment: For (b), after partitioning the vertices as you did and deducing there must be $13$ edges, do we just draw the/a graph by trial and error? Or is there more stuff that needs to be figured out? Thanks.

Comment: I followed the straightforward way of drawing the graph first and then used some guesswork to correct/complete it but its easier to guess since there are not many options available.